# MarshMallow Permission for gmaps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-6.0-marshmallow

If `gmaps` needs this permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

1. should I ask for each one to the user with `requestPermissions` ?
2. I checked some times and it only crash saying that the user didnt give permissions for `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`but not the others, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I ask for each one to the user with `requestPermissions` ?

First when to use requestPermission ?

[requestPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestPermissions%28java.lang.String[],%20int%29) is only call after [checkSelfPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkSelfPermission%28java.lang.String%29) when this method doesn't return `PERMISSION_GRANTED`.

You can find a [list of permission](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html) that android M requires during the runtime. Each of these Permissions are part of a Permission group. `WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION` is from `android.permission-group.STORAGE` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` / `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` are from `android.permission-group.LOCATION`.

If the user allows the access to a permission -for example `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`-, then android will automatically grant the access of this permission group -i.e. `permission-group.LOCATION`-. So if you later `checkSelfPermission` for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, you should receive `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`.

If you app crashes, it means that you tried to call, for example `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` before requesting from the user the permission-group Location.

**Edit:**

Do not forget that `requestPermission` is **asynchronous**. So **do not call a method that requires a permission right after requestPermission**. To call a method that requires a permission, you should override [onRequestPermissionsResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRequestPermissionsResult%28int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[]%29) that give you a list of permission and their state -granted/denied-.

Comment: You can also check the android pattern video that explained the process https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc-lJo_RGGXL2Psr8vVCTWjM&v=C8lUdPVSzDk

Answer (score 3):

You should only need to request permission for the LOCATION and STORAGE groups. I'm also pretty sure Fine location includes permission for Coarse, so you don't need to include that line in your manifest.

Comment: what do you mean by `Fine location includes permission for Coarse`? If I ask one permission then it will be granted for all on the same group?

Comment: `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` is for mobile cell data and wifi and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and for mobile cell data, wifi and GPS. So Fine location "includes" Coarse Location.